# Cloud SQL HA - Failback to which zone?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

On Google's [Cloud SQL HA documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/high-availability) It says

> If you need to have the primary instance in the zone that had the
> outage, you can do a failback. A failback performs the same steps as
> the failover, only in the opposite direction, to reroute traffic back
> to the original instance.

Example of set up:

```
Primary-Instance-A in zone A  
Standby-Instance-B in zone B
```

~A failover will switch their zones~

```
Primary-Instance-A becomes the standby instance in zone B.   
Standby-Instance-B becomes the primary instance in zone A.
```

If a failback is configured, `it will reroute traffic back to the original instance`.

The original instance will be in zone B after failover. So a failback will reroute to zone B?

Why is there a need to reroute traffic when both instances are identical and within the same region?

Answer (score 3):

The failback option is only available after a recent failover. So if you need to have the primary instance in the zone that had the outage, you can do a failback.

A failback performs the same steps as the failover, only in the opposite direction, to reroute traffic back to the original instance.

You can see the failback option in top right of your console.

I hope it clears your doubt. Also, I am giving the link below so that you can check more about it and can read in detail. Please refer the link below:

https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/high-availability#failover-overview

Comment: Hi, thanks. I am wondering ```The original instance will be in zone B after failover. So a failback will reroute to zone B? Why is there a need to reroute traffic when both instances are identical and within the same region?```

Answer (score 2):

After a failover, the instance that received the failover continues to be the primary instance, even after the original instance comes back online. Once the zone or instance that experienced an outage becomes available again, the original primary instance is destroyed and recreated.